# How to print screenshot with "fit to page" option?

Tags: printing, screen-capture

When I use "Grab" to take a screen shot and then print it I have to manually adjust the "scale %" to make it fit on one page.
I'm looking for an "fit to page" option.

I'm also using the "awesome screenshot" app but it doesn't have a print feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a way to do this in Grab.  However, if you use Preview, you can do the same thing as Grab, by going to File > Take Screen Shot > (Selection).  You can then use the scale to fit page function, as shown below.  Preview has many hidden and cool features that not many people know about.  You don't really need to use Grab, when you could just use Preview, and get what you want!  Hope this helps!

(Screenshot taken with Preview)

[image]